# Rewrite url in social engine

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, socialengine

I am using social engine, I want to change my url from www.example.com/signup to www.example.com/activate, sorry I want to keep both urls. please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your public/index.php file.

```
$FrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$Router = $FrontController->getRouter();
$Router->addRoute("activate",
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
(
"/activate",
array
("controller" => "signup",
"action" => "index"
)
));
```

here: activate is the name of the router. /activate is the url you want as address, controller and action is self descriptive.

Comment: there is no index.php file in my public folder

Comment: Put the code in the bootstrap file then. I think that will also work. Or put the code in the file which is calling the boot strap. But put the coding before calling bootstrap.

Comment: You are working on zend framework right??? If you are using zend framework, there should be a index.php in your public folder.

Answer (score 2):

In application/modules/Use/settings/manifest find these lines:

```
    'user_signup' => array(
        'route' => '/signup/:action/*',
        'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'user',
        'controller' => 'signup',
        'action' => 'index'
     )
```

Change `/signup/:action/` to `/activate/:action`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your .htaccess to create redirects, refer to [this example](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml)